# Gradle Build Error: Execution failed for task ':app:prepareDebugDependencies'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Please help me to fix this error:

> Warning:Project app: apk-only dependencies can only be jars.
>    com.google.android.gms:play-services:aar:6.5.87 is an Android Library.
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:prepareDebugDependencies'.
>   Dependency Error. See console for details.

This is my Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.palletdesig.colopovideo"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    apk 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.3.0.jar')
}
```

And the console output:

> Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar,
>   :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]
>
> Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
>   WARNING: Project app: apk-only dependencies can only be jars.   com.google.android.gms:play-services:aar:6.5.87 is an Android Library.
>   WARNING: Project app: apk-only dependencies can only be jars.  com.google.android.gms:play-services:aar:6.5.87 is an Android Library.
>       Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
>       :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:checkDebugManifest
>       :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library
>       :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices6587Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareDebugDependencies
>       Project app: apk-only dependencies can only be jars.   com.google.android.gms:play-services:aar:6.5.87 is an Android Library.
>
> FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:prepareDebugDependencies'.
>
>   > Dependency Error. See console for details.
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
>   BUILD FAILED
>
>   Total time: 3.097 secs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
apk 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
```